# API authentication with Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-socialite

I have implemented API authentication using Passport and trying to do the same using Socialite but I am getting runtime exception error

> Session store not set on request

This is what the endpoints look like following the laravel 5.8 documentation

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'AuthController@facebookRedirect');

Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'AuthController@facebookCallback');
```

In service.php file I have added facebook key like so

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id'     =>  env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect'      => env('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL'),
],
```

And the `AuthController` methods are

```
public function facebookRedirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function facebookCallback()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

    $user->token;
}
```

In Postman and my browser I have called the api end point like this
`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/facebook`

What am I doing wrong? Is this the way to do API authentication using socialite?

Answer (score 0):

it think you need to remove `stateless()` from function `facebookCallback`:

```
  public function facebookCallback()
  {
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    $user->token;
   }
`
```

if you are using `sessions` you shouldn't use `stateless()`

Comment: Having `stateless()` chained to return statement is how session state verification is disabled.